# How to echo a custom object in PHP?

Tags: php, class, object, echo

Given a particular class, `TheClass`, with an instance *foo*, is there any way to have PHP `echo foo;` in a customized manner?

```
class TheClass {
    public $Name;
    public $Number;
    function MrFunction() { /* bla bla bla */ }
}

$foo = new TheClass();

echo $foo;
```

As I understand, you cannot overload `echo` and I realize I could easily have `$foo->MrFunction()` do the work. However I am wondering if there is a way to code in which

`echo $foo` prints out `$foo->Name` and `$foo->Number`.

We're using *PHP Version 5.2.6* but upgrading is not an issue.

Comment: What makes the magic methods 'magic'?

Comment: every time you use them an elephant gets its tusks....

Comment: @my younger self - they're magic because they are called automatically during execution, without explicitly being called by the developer

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
class TheClass {
    public $Name;
    public $Number;
    function MrFunction() { /* bla bla bla */ }

   public function __toString()
   {
     return $this->Name . ' '. $this->Number;
   }
}


echo $theClassInstance;
```

Comment: You want need `(string)` casting as `echo` explicitly does that for you

Answer (score 33):

I think you are looking for `print_r($foo)`, or `var_dump($foo)`.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, using the [__toString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) magic method

Answer (score 8):

What you need is the `__toString()` magic method. The example in the docs should show what you need.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring: